# Sorting my list by hours and printing a table,

Tags: python, list, sorting, printing

I feel like I'm so close to the answer but after trying various methods suggested on similar problem on this site, I'm not closer to the answer.

I've tagged in the actual assignment what I borrowed from here (so I'm not accidentally stealing code) but removed it here to make it easier to read. What I'm looking to do is keep my three functions (that is taking the input, removing the colon, and then printing a sorted table from the list i.e.:

> "Enter time for your next appointment (as hh:mm): 17:30
>   Enter a short description: COSC1306
>
> Appointment at 17:30 COSC 1306"

This is what I have:

```
alpha = []
while len(alpha) >= 0: 
    gamma = input("Enter time for your next appointment (as hh:mm): ")
    (h, m) = gamma.split(':')
    result = str(h) + str(m)
    delta = input("Enter a short description: ")
    alpha.append([result, delta])
    sorted(alpha)
    for table in alpha:
        print("Appointment at %s %s" %(table[0],", ".join(map(str,table[1:]))))
```

I want the table to be sorted by what "time" the appointment is and not just in the order I typed it. Is there anyone who might be able to help me with that?

Comment: Okay, I tried to fix it up a bit. I cleaned it up to here:

`alpha = []  
while len(alpha) >= 0:   
gamma = input("Enter time for your next appointment (as hh:mm): ")  
delta = input("Enter a short description: ")  
alpha.append([gamma, delta])  
    sorted.alpha[0]`  

but printing it sorted in the table format did not work either way I sorted it, so I'm wondering if that is the code I need to revisit... Sorry for all the hullabaloo you guys. I hate myself for being the epitome of a newb..

Answer (score 0):

I think replacing `sorted(alpha)` with the following should work:

```
alpha = sorted(alpha, key=lambda x: (x[0]))
```

Comment: lists of tuples/lists are already sorted by the first member.

Comment: Correct, so either `alpha.sort()` as you mentioned, or `alpha = sorted(alpha)` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(alpha)
sorted(alpha)
print(alpha)
```

Notice that alpha is unchanged.  `sorted` returns a NEW list, which is immediately discarded.  If you want to sort in-place, do

```
alpha.sort()
```